# get variable from url in php and store in database

Tags: php, mysql

this is the example link http://geekzzz.tk/about/inde.php?payment_id=MOJO642000F92571423&status=success  And i need to store the payment_id in my database. Whenever the user opens the same link again, then the url should not work. I think $_GET() code is the thing that we can store but i don't know how to do that. Please can anyone explain me in detail. I am a beginner. Help me

Comment: please show what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. You have to use the `$_GET` Method here. IN your page just use the following codes:

```
$payment_id = $_GET['payment_id'];
```

The variable now hold/ store the `url` payment id. Now you can insert it into the database. And if you want to check and store the payment id then first make a select query to check the payment id already exist or not, if not then insert.

> Note: Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for the security reason.

The `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.

Comment: you don't know about how to insert a value into the database??? Start with this link [sql_insert](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: Can you please write down the full code Mr Frayne Konok.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to use `$_GET`:

> http://geekzzz.tk/about/inde.php?payment_id=MOJO642000F92571423&status=success

```
<?php

$payment_id = $_GET['payment_id'];
// will hold value 'MOJO642000F92571423'

$success = $_GET['success'];
// will hold value 'success'

?>
```

Then, you can insert `$payment_id` and `$success` into database. Remember to escape it using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: In which page do i have to write this code. Please help me here

Answer (score 0):

if you already created database and made connection then

Just get your variable like this and store it in a database

```
<?php

$Payment_id=$_GET["payment_id"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO mydatabase(payment_id) values($Payment_id);

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)

{

echo "data stored successfully"; //CHECKING

}

else

{

echo "data still not received";  //CHECKING

}

?>
```